# Change keybinding for up/down when in vim popup

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, plugin-deoplete

I'm using `deoplete` plugin for auto completion. In Vim, default keybinding for up and down when popup appears is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>. I want to change to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> for same behavior with `CtrlP` plugin.

How can I change this. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't "directly" map keys in the pop-up menu, you'll have to use [`expression mappings`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-%3Cexpr%3E) and the [`pumvisible()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#pumvisible%28%29) function to check if the popup menu is visible.

```
inoremap <expr> <C-j> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<C-j>"
inoremap <expr> <C-k> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<C-k>"
```

If the popup menu is visible `<C-j>` is mapped to `<C-n>` to make it go to the next entry. If the menu isn't visible `<C-j>` is mapped to `<C-j>`.